# Consider polynomial $q(x,y)=(2x+3y)^2-1$, how to show that it has roots with arbitrary values of x,y?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Given the following polynomial $q(x,y)=(2x+3y)^2-1$. How would I show that it has roots with any large $x,y$?

Comment: What does arbitrary large coordinates mean?

Comment: What happens if we choose $(x,y)$ such that $2x+3y=\pm1$?

Comment: By the way all the roots lies on this line.

Comment: @GitGud values of x and y.

Comment: @BluePonyInc. I still don't understand. Hopefully someone who understands the question will provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't speak analyst slang, so I might have misunderstood the question.

Note that $$\begin{align} \displaystyle \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\colon q(x,y)=0\}&=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\colon(2x+3y)^2=1\}\\&=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\colon 2x+3y=\pm 1\}\\&=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y=\frac{\pm 1-2x}{3}\right\}.\end{align}$$

As $x$ gets larger, $y$ will get smaller as it will be negative.

Therefore you can't get arbitrarily large roots for the equation.